# Looping Through the Same Animation on List Elements Without Numerous Callback Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

My intent with this is to go through each list element and animate it into view while shifting it to the right 30px with `marginLeft`. I'm trying to get a delay of 6 seconds in between each animation. So far I can only get the first and second list elements to do this. How can I make it so that it goes through every single list element without using a bunch of callback functions? Note that the `.animate-list` class is the `.ul` element. I also need the first list element to appear when the document loads and then every list element after to be delayed by 6 seconds.

```
function doAnimate(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.animate-list li').css({
                    opacity:0,
                    marginLeft : '0px'
                });
    });

    $('.animate-list li:first-child').animate({
        opacity:1,
        marginLeft : '30px'
    },1000,'linear',function nextAnimate(){

    $(this).next('li').delay(6000).animate({
            opacity:1,
            marginLeft:'30px'
            },1000,'linear',function(){
            nextAnimate; // loop back to next 'li' ???
        });

    });
};

doAnimate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on to T.J. Crowder's answer, I was able to make it such that the first list element appears when the document loads, and then the rest animate with a 6 second delay:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var i, list;

    list = $('.animate-list li');

    list.css({
        opacity: 0,
        marginLeft: '0px'
    });


    i = -1;
    animate();

    function animate() {
        if (++i < list.length) {
            if (i == 0) {
                list.eq(i).animate({
                    opacity: 1,
                    marginLeft: '30px'
                }, 1000, 'linear', animate);
            }
            else {
                list.eq(i).delay(6000).animate({
                    opacity: 1,
                    marginLeft: '30px'
                }, 1000, 'linear', animate);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a counter and have the animation function call itself when done with each item:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i, list;

  list = $('.animate-list li');

  list.css({
    opacity: 0,
    marginLeft: '0px'
  });

  i = -1;
  animate();

  function animate() {
    if (++i < list.length) {
      list.eq(i).animate({
        opacity: 1,
        marginLeft: '30px'
      }, 1000, 'linear', animate);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<ul class="animate-list">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>
  <li>Fifth</li>
  <li>Sixth</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I apologize for not making it clearer. I need the first list element to appear when the document loads and not without a 6000 ms delay. I will revise my question.

Comment: @user3386635: It's easy to adjust the above to do that. The fundamental technique is the point of the answer, not writing the exact code you need.

Comment: My apologies, I'm still new to Javascript even though I primarily code in Java. I was thinking too much, when, in reality, the general concepts are all the same!

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Car is to Carpet.

Comment: I was alluding to the general concepts of OOP.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a combination of  :

- promises generated by the  "fx" queues of each LI element
- `array.reduce()` to efficiently create a .then() chain comprising the required animation sequence.

The code is concise but will look slightly alien if you are not familiar with promises :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 //This function initiates an animation and returns a promise of its completion
 function anim(li) {
  return $(li).animate({
   opacity: 1,
   marginLeft: '30px'
  }, 1000, 'linear').delay(6000).promise();//.promise() generates a promise of completion of the animation
 }
 
 $('.animate-list li').css({ // initial CSS (hide)
  opacity: 0,
  marginLeft: '0px'
 }).get().reduce(function(p, li) {
  return p.then(function() {
   return anim(li);
  });
 }, $.when());//$.when() is a resolved promise to get the then() chain started.
});
```

```html
<ul class="animate-list">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>
  <li>Fifth</li>
  <li>Sixth</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*Note: no messy counters!*

`.get()` is necessary to convert the jQuery collection to a proper javascript Array, thus making `.reduce()` available.

Returning `p.then(...)` from the reduction funtion has the effect of progressively building the required `.then()` chain. The nett effect is the same as :

```
var lis = $(".animate-list li").get();

$.when().then(function() {
    anim(lis[0]);
}).then(function() {
    anim(lis[1]);
}).then(function() {
    anim(lis[2]);
})..... etc.
```